# Combining a wired network with an ad-hoc network

Tags: networking, lan, ad-hoc-network

I have two Windows Vista computers (A & B) with an ad-hoc network connecting them. Can I somehow then connect computer C with A through a switch/router and have all three computers on "one" network?

Comment: @ Yes, you just have to bridge the connections for wireless A->B and wired A>C. I assume machine A has wired and wireless network connections. This is very simple to do in windows. You can just select the two network interfaces and "bridge" the connections.

link|edit|flag
answered Aug 13 '09 at 20:20
@Troggy♦ i've tried this already... i have similar problem...except i have Win 7 in my main PC and i'm trying to share its wired internet connection on my nokia c6 using ad-hoc on win7 computer...i'm using a Netgear Wireless USB Adapter for this...
can u help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just have to bridge the connections for wireless A->B and wired A>C. I assume machine A has wired and wireless network connections. This is very simple to do in windows. You can just select the two network interfaces and "bridge" the connections.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Just connect each of them to a switch with normal patch cables (as opposed to the cross over cable you might currently be using).  You will have to assign static IPs (which I assume you are doing already) and keep them all on the same subnet and in the same workgroup.  But, other than that, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

A home router can connect multiple computers onto one network and also the Internet. routers can also setup the IPs for you.

[Buy one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=4025&Description=router&name=%2425%20-%20%2450).

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't what I was asking for...

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use a **Network Switch** on A, B, & C(for wired connection) and assign an IP for each.

A: IP=10.0.0.101 SUBNET = 255.0.0.0 GATEWAY: 10.0.0.1
B: IP=10.0.0.102 SUBNET = 255.0.0.0 GATEWAY: 10.0.0.1
C: IP=10.0.0.103 SUBNET = 255.0.0.0 GATEWAY: 10.0.0.1

or

A: IP=192.168.0.101 SUBNET = 255.0.0.0 GATEWAY: 192.168.0.1
B: IP=192.168.0.102 SUBNET = 255.0.0.0 GATEWAY: 192.168.0.1
C: IP=192.168.0.103 SUBNET = 255.0.0.0 GATEWAY: 192.168.0.1

Just leave the DNS blank.

But if you want it to be Wireless. just use a **Wireless Router**.
no need to assign an IP. It will automatically an IP for Computer A, B, & C.

Comment: Yes, but that was not what I was asking for.