# How to establish a ad-hoc Network between 2 Laptops via Wi-Fi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ad-hoc-network

I have 2 laptops and One of the Laptop is connected to Internet via Ethernet.

I would like to establish a ad-hoc network between these 2 laptops. Any suggestions/pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: What operating system does the laptop with the internet connection have ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining a wired network with an ad-hoc network](http://superuser.com/questions/22424/combining-a-wired-network-with-an-ad-hoc-network)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7 see this serverfault question: [Windows 7 - wireless connection sharing](https://serverfault.com/questions/29117/windows-7-wireless-connection-sharing)

---

On a Mac laptop go to System Preferences

Under the Internet & Network section select Sharing

Check the box next to Internet Sharing

Select Ethernet 1 from the drop down "share your connection from"

Under "To computer using:" check the box for Airport

[image]